# Can I access an app running via Amazon ECS (docker) on an EC2 instance via localhost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Suppose I have two apps launched via the AWS ECS cluster (using Docker containers).

I want to expose one app to the world via a public IP (and I do it via the AWS load balancer) but the other one I want to be able to access only internally, so that it would not have any public IPs and would only be accessible internally.

Is this possible to do that at all? I suppose it should be easier via docker containers because I could possibly make them communicate to each other by exposing a localhost via

`--network="host"` in `docker run`

But that would work if I run the two apps on the same EC2 instance.

What if I run them on separate instances but they are using the same load balancer or — separate instances but in the same AWS zone?

What setting would I use in ECS to expose this app only via the localhost?

Comment: The client and containers will never be on the same EC2 instance so they'll never be `localhost`.  You should be able to set up an internal load balancer in front of the ECS service, and connect to that from within your AWS VPC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/) for internal communication or Load Balancer.

> I want to expose one app to the world via a public IP (and I do it via
> the AWS load balancer) but the other one I want to be able to access
> only internally

So you actually you are interested to run two services for example

- Service A
- Service B

Attach [internet-facing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html) LB with `service A` to make `service A` available for public use.

User [Internal Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html) or service discovery to communicate with `service B`  which only available with in-network.

> What setting would I use in ECS to expose this app only via the
> localhost?

There is no localhost(this container only), so to deal with question use an internal Load balancer.

> What if I run them on separate instances but they are using the same
> load balancer or — separate instances but in the same AWS zone?

With a load balancer, you run hundred of replicas and hundred of ECS instances AWS will route and manage traffic accordingly.